# Angular 5- *ngIf with Comparison to Variable- Syntax

Tags: angular, typescript

I am looking to display various navigation tabs conditionally- depending on the current route which I always have stored in a global variable in my project.

Here, I'm trying to access my global 'current_route' variable from my 'authService' and compare it to a string, which will determine which nav tabs I show.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <div *ngIf='"authService.current_route"  === "site/map"'>
    <li (click)="changeroute()">
      <a [routerLink]="['']">Current Site</a>
    </li>
    <li (click)="changeroute()">
      <a [routerLink]="['/sites/map']">Site Map</a>
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

1. What's the proper syntax for this? Do I need braces {{}}? I can't seem to get anything to work. Thanks.

My component looks like

```
  ...
  constructor(private router: Router, public authService: AuthService, ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.current_route = this.router.url
    console.log(this.authService.current_route)
    console.log(typeof(this.authService.current_route))

  }
  changeroute() {
    this.authService.current_route = this.router.url
    console.log(this.authService.current_route)

  }

}
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You generally use `interpolation syntax {{}}` when you want to get the value of a particular variable. For `property binding syntax []`, you can just specify the name of the property that you want to bind to. Or you can also specify an expression which will result in a value. If you want to assign a string value to a property using the property binding syntax but don't want to define a property on your Component Class, you can do this as well:

```
<html-element-name-or-component-selector  
  [propertyName]="'propertyValue'">
</html-element-name-or-component-selector>
```

`*ngIf` should be used like property binding syntax. So it can be assigned either a property name or an expression. In your case, it's an expression that returns a boolean. So changing your *ngIf block to this:

```
<div *ngIf="authService.current_route === 'site/map'" >
```

would work.

Also you've used property binding syntax for `routerLink` as well which wasn't really required.

So you can change it to this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <div *ngIf='"authService.current_route"  === "site/map"' >
        <li (click)="changeroute()"><a routerLink="/" >Current Site</a></li>
        <li (click)="changeroute()"><a routerLink="/sites/map">Site Map</a></li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

Also, as Antonis suggested, you shouldn't be using such logic on the template. They should be defined on Component Classes instead. That way it's loosely coupled, with better separation of concerns and is also better for unit testing.

So as suggested by him, created a getter:

```
get onSiteMap(): boolean {
  return this.authService.current_route === 'site/map';
}
```

And then update your condition accordingly:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <div *ngIf="onSiteMap">
    <li (click)="changeroute()">
      <a routerLink="/">Current Site</a>
    </li>
    <li (click)="changeroute()">
      <a routerLink="/sites/map">Site Map</a>
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

NOTE: Please do make sure that `console.log(this.authService.current_route)` is returning 'site/map'. Or in case it's returning anything else, please update the `*ngIf` condition in the template accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Since your case is very specific, I suggest you use a getter so you keep your template cleaner and you can change the logic inside your component easier.

component:

```
get isOnSiteMap(): boolean {
  return this.authService.current_route === 'site/map'
}
```

template:

```
<div *ngIf="isOnSiteMap">
```